# What do these mysterious numbers in the subject line of arXiv mailing list emails mean?

Tags: arxiv

Every day I receive the latest arXiv abstracts via email, with subject lines such as

`physics daily Subj-class mailing a4 1`
`physics daily Subj-class mailing 124 1`
`physics daily Subj-class mailing 490 1`

With new email clients that create "conversations" from an email chain based on the subject line, the disorderly nature of the subject lines makes it a pain to sift through the last week's abstracts if I haven't kept myself up to date.

What do `a4`, `124`, and `490` mean? These identifiers are not unique to each day's listings, but I cannot spot a correlation between them and the date of the email. Is there some hidden way to either include the date in the subject header, or remove these seemingly random strings?

Comment: Have you ever contacted the arxiv support to ask your question?

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent Not yet. I thought I'd make sure as best I can that the answer is indeed a mystery before I email the (busy!) arXiv admins. If the bounty expires un-answered then I will email them.

Comment: You may not believe, but I read almost every page of the help of the site, but I could not find any answer relevant to your question.

Comment: As a data point, I subscribe to one category (cs.CG), and I have only seen the numbers `2`, `4`, `8`, and `10`. So they seem to be in a base > 10 (hexadecimal?), and somehow related to powers of 2.

Comment: @Mangara mine quite does not look so: `math daily Subj-class mailing 100020 26`

Comment: @tohecz While that isn't a power of two, it is the sum of two powers of two: 2^20 and 2^5. So perhaps it's a bit mask?

Comment: And interpreted as a hexadecimal encoding of a bit vector, the OP's numbers all have three bits set.

Comment: I have emailed help@arXiv. I'll answer the question myself if there is a useful response.

Answer (score 11):

Straight from the horse's mouth: there is no fix, but an update is on the list of things that "will be done when they're done".

> You may safely ignore the numbers after the text "class mailing" as
>   they are used for internal audit code and essentially meaningless from
>   a user perspective.
>
> We do have plans to update the mailing code at some stage, but the
>   time-line is unclear due to limited developer time.

Comment: Is this from a public page on arXiv.org?

Comment: @episanty No. Once it was obvious no one here knew I emailed help@arXiv, this was their response.

Answer (score -2):

They look like hexadecimal. So they may be the beginning of a hash or UUID. This would be similar to what git uses to refer to specific versions in a repository. If this is the case, they are effectively random and you aren't going to find any correlation with the outside world (which is the point).

Comment: Why was this answer so downvoted. As it turns out this was actually fairly close to the answer in that there is no usable correlation and the only way to get an answer, it appears was to mail the sysadmins, which the author should have done in the first place, and therefor it appears he made no 'real' research effort originally. I'm just curious.

Comment: @CGCampbell Perhaps in hindsight the downvoting is a little perverse, given that it was pretty close to the answer of the first of my two questions. **But** an objective question demands an authoritative answer, not an obvious piece of guesswork (this answer would have been more appropriate as a comment), so I do still feel that it is justified. If you read the comments to the original question, you'll see that I asked here first in case I could avoid bothering the arXiv admins. Not a lack of research effort - just respect for others' time.